# View class into a container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference

I'm trying to write a class `View` to serve as a view into another container, (a sparse matrix class, but that should be unimportant for the question).

`View` should contain references (e.g. `std::reference_wrapper`) to a selection of elements in the container, and have methods returning references to those elements, as well as an assignment operator making one block equal to another.

My problem is that I want `View` to be able to take values in addition to references: both be constructed from values as a non-reference instance to be used in assignments, and assign values to single elements in a reference instance.

An MVE of the code so far is:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t size>
class View
{

    private:
        std::array<T, size> _values;

    public:
        View(const std::array<T, size> & values)
            : _values{ values } { }
        // ----------
        View<T, size> & operator=(const View<T, size> & other)
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
                this->get(i) = other.get(i);
            }
            return *this;
        }
        // ----------
        T & get(size_t idx)
        {
            return _values.at(idx);
        }
        const T & get(size_t idx) const
        {
            return _values.at(idx);
        }

};
```

It can be used like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int values[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    View<int, 2> v1{
        {values[0], values[1]}
    };
    View<std::reference_wrapper<int>, 2> v2{
        {values[3], values[4]}
    };

    // WHAT WORKS

    v1.get(0) = 10;  // can assign to the non reference `View<int, size>`,
                     // works as intended

    v2.get(0) += 9;  // can increment through the reference wrappers,
                     // this also works as intended

    // WHAT THAT DOES NOT WORK

    // v2 = v1;  // nether of these work, as there is no conversion
    // v1 = v2;  // between `View<std::reference_wrapper<int>, size>`
                 // and `View<int, size>`. It is the first expression
                 // that is of most interest

    // v2.get(1) = 10;     // this doesn't work as the return is a
                           // `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, not a
                           // reference to an `int`
    v2.get(1).get() = 10;  // this works as a work-around to
                           // this problem, but it feels clunky, and it
                           // makes the interface between the two types
                           // different

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
        std::cout << v1.get(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        std::cout << values[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This should output:

```
10 2
1 2 3 13 10
```

I'm using `clang++` to compile on Ubuntu 15.10.

---

So specifically,

1. How should I implement the assignment operator to allow `View<T, size>` and `View<std::reference_wrapper<T>, size>` to be assigned to each other (or at least the former to be assigned to latter). Creating two versions

   ```
   View<T, size> & operator=(const View<T, size> & other);
   View<T, size> & operator=(
       const View<std::reference_wrapper<T>, size> & other);
   ```

   does not work, (as a `View<std::reference_wrapper<T>, size>` then would need a `View<std::reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T> >, size>` for the second overload).
2. How can I write the `get(size_t idx)` methods such that the return is `T &` for both`View<T, size>` and `View<std::reference_wrapper<T>, size>`?

---

I have a feeling this can be accomplished by using templates somehow, but I'm still quite new to template programming so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: When assigning from `View<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` to the same type, do you want the value of the reference to be assign or the reference themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to make `get()` return `T&` for `T` and `std::reference_wrapper<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct get_value_type {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_value_type<std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T, size_t size>
class View {
    using value_type = typename get_value_type<T>::type;

    value_type & get(size_t idx) {
        return _values.at(idx);
    }

    const value_type & get(size_t idx) const {
        return _values.at(idx);
    }
};
```

The `get_value_type` template help us obtain `T` from both `T` and `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, then you simply change the return type of `get()` to `value_type`, and since `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is implicitly convertible to `T&` it works.

Now that you have access to `value_type`, you can use it to create your two `operator=`:

```
View& operator= (const View<value_type, size> & other) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        this->get(i) = other.get(i);
    }
    return *this;
}

View& operator=(const View<std::reference_wrapper<value_type>, size> & other) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        this->get(i) = other.get(i);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

In case you want to allow assignment from different view (e.g. a view of `int` to a view of `double`), you could use a templated version:

```
template <typename U>
View<T, size> & operator=(const View<U, size> & other) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        this->get(i) = other.get(i);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

---

A small addition that may be a bit off-topic but instead of having an `std::array` attribute, you could inherit from `std::array` like the following:

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
struct View: public std::array<T, Size> {

    using array_type = std::array<T, Size>;
    using value_type = typename get_value_type<T>::type;

    View (std::array<T, Size> const& values) : array_type (values) { }

    View& operator=(const View<value_type, Size> & other) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            (*this)[i] = other[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    View& operator=(const View<std::reference_wrapper<value_type>, Size> & other) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
            (*this)[i] = other[i];
        }
        return *this;
    } 

    value_type & operator[](size_t idx) {
        return array_type::operator[](idx);
    }


    const value_type & operator[](size_t idx) const {
        return array_type::operator[](idx);
    }

};
```

This would allow you to use a lot of stuff from the standard library on your `View` without having to redefine anything.

Comment: Great, thank!
I think its okay for `operator=(...)` to be templated as you have proposed. But if I need it stricter isn't it enough to definine two overloads like `operator=(const View<value_type, size> &)` and `operator=(const View<std::reference_wrapper<value_type>, size> &)`? Or is there a different way?

Comment: @eistaa This should work. I actually did the trick for `operator=` before the trick for `get()` so I did not thought of using `value_type` inside `operator=`.

Comment: @eistaa Also (see the end of my edited answer), you could inherit from `std::array` instead of storing an instance of it. This would allow you to use a lot of standard library stuff with your `View` without having to implement anything (e.g. range-based for loop, standard algorithms, ...).

Comment: Interresting idea. I will consider it, it could save some work depending on how complex operations I will need on the views.